# Plot function error

Tags: r, function, plot, viewport

I am running the `leaps` package a number of times on different data sets. This produces a number of different figures. Because I am trying to run it quite a few times I wanted to transform this into a plotting function, allowing me to apply it more easily. But I am not great at functions yet and it something rather bizarre has gone wrong - I suspect this is because I have wrote the function incorrectly somewhere along the lines!

```
FUNCTIONNAME <- function(A, B, C){

plot.new()
vp0 <- viewport(x=0, y = 0.9, just = c("center"))
vp1 <- viewport(x=0,y=0,width=0.5, height=1, just = c("left", "bottom"))
vp2 <- viewport(x=0.5,y=0,width=0.5, height=1, just = c("left", "bottom"))

pushViewport(vp1)
par(new=TRUE, fig=gridFIG())
plot.regsubsetsMOD((A), scale = "bic", main = NULL, cex.main = 0.5, cex.axis = 0.65)
grid.text("BIC", 0.55, 0.825)
upViewport()

pushViewport(vp2)
par(new=TRUE, fig=gridFIG())
plot.regsubsetsMOD((A), scale = "r2", main = NULL, cex.main = 0.5, cex.axis = 0.65)
grid.text("R2", 0.55, 0.825)
upViewport()

pushViewport(vp0)
grid.text("B")

dev.copy(png,"C", height = 400, width = 1000)
dev.off()

}

FUNCTIONNAME(A = "Aut_Q_PCA_Models", B = "'textstring'", C = "'textstring.png'" )
```

The error I get is:

> "Error in lsum$rsq : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors"

This confuses me because `lsum$rsq` is in the `plot.regsubsetsMOD` function, not my plotting one. The `plot.regsubsetsMOD` function normally works correctly so I believe the error is not in there - it is in my new function for plotting the `viewport`. Any help would be much appreciated!

#

Here is the full code of the page as it stands:

```
library(leaps)
library(grid)
library(gridBase)

#####Apply leaps to first data set
setwd("J:/Academic papers/Dissertation journal paper/Version 3/New analysis/R code/Full data/AutumnLIFE-ChalkRiver")

AutumnLIFEChalkRiver <- read.csv("AutumnLIFE-ChalkRiver.csv",header=T)
attach(AutumnLIFEChalkRiver)

Aut_Q_PCA <- AutumnLIFEChalkRiver[,c(3, 6, 7, 10, 12, 16)]

Aut_Q_PCA_Models <-regsubsets(AutumnChalkLife~.,
                          data=Aut_Q_PCA,
                          nbest=5)

#####Generate figure
setwd("J:/R/Leaps")
FUNCTIONNAME(A ="Aut_Q_PCA_Models", B = "'textstring'", C = "'textstring.png'" )
```

#

The code `plot.regsubsetsMOD` is a modification of the `leaps` code, but it is very minor, I simply added `...` on a few lines so that I could change the plots to be more legible:

```
plot.regsubsetsMOD <- function (x, labels = obj$xnames, main = NULL, scale = c("bic", 
                                                                               "Cp", "adjr2", "r2"), col = gray(seq(0, 0.9, length = 10)), 
                                ...) 
{
  obj <- x
  lsum <- summary(obj)
  par(mar = c(7, 5, 6, 3) + 0.1)
  nmodels <- length(lsum$rsq)
  np <- obj$np
  propscale <- FALSE
  sscale <- pmatch(scale[1], c("bic", "Cp", "adjr2", "r2"), 
                   nomatch = 0)
  if (sscale == 0) 
    stop(paste("Unrecognised scale=", scale))
  if (propscale) 
    stop(paste("Proportional scaling only for probabilities"))
  yscale <- switch(sscale, lsum$bic, lsum$cp, lsum$adjr2, lsum$rsq)
  up <- switch(sscale, -1, -1, 1, 1)
  index <- order(yscale * up)
  colorscale <- switch(sscale, yscale, yscale, -log(pmax(yscale, 
                                                         1e-04)), -log(pmax(yscale, 1e-04)))
  image(z = t(ifelse(lsum$which[index, ], colorscale[index], 
                     NA + max(colorscale) * 1.5)), xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n", 
        x = (1:np), y = 1:nmodels, xlab = "", ylab = "", 
        col = col)
  laspar <- par("las")
  on.exit(par(las = laspar))
  par(las = 2)
  axis(1, at = 1:np, labels = labels, ...) #Modified
  axis(2, at = 1:nmodels, labels = signif(yscale[index], 2), ...) #Modified
  if (!is.null(main)) 
    title(main = main, ...) #Modified
  box()
  invisible(NULL)
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `LEAP` (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/LEAP/index.html) or `leaps` (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/leaps/index.html)?

Comment: It would be helpfull if you provide all code to have it reproducible. Especially `plot.regsubsetsMOD` is unclear. It seems as it is a modification of `plot.regsubsets` from the `leaps` package. Service for other readers: the function `viewport` requires the package `grid`  and `pushViewport` requires `gridBase`.

Comment: I mean     `leaps`, my code was editted :) The figures used in my function here are generated from     `leaps`

Comment: and where does `gridFIG` come from?

Comment: @Qaswed Thank you, I have added more information to the code to cover these things - the modification of leaps was extremely minor
@ Spacedman `gridFIG` was necessary to stop a margin error

Comment: @Spacedman  `gridFIG` also comes from `gridBase`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main thing to understand is that `"A"` is a string, containing the letter *A*. It it remains this even if a variable is named `A` being a string containing the letters *Aut_Q_PCA_Models*. In other words `"A"` and `A` are different things (as long one defined `A <- "A"`). The same thing holds for `"B"` vs. `B` and `"C"` vs. `C`.

Your plotting function, you named `FUNCTIONNAME` calls the function `plot.regsubsetsMOD`. As you wrote it starts with

```
plot.regsubsetsMOD <- function (x, labels = obj$xnames, main = NULL, scale = c("bic", Cp", "adjr2", "r2"), col = gray(seq(0, 0.9, length = 10)), 
                            ...) 
{
obj <- x
lsum <- summary(obj)
par(mar = c(7, 5, 6, 3) + 0.1)
nmodels <- length(lsum$rsq)
```

Your plotting function parses `A = "Aut_Q_PCA_Models"` to it. So the problem occurs when basically R tries to run `summary("Aut_Q_PCA_Models")$rsq`. To run a summary on a single string is apparently senseless. As you named your model from the `regsubsets`-class *Aut_Q_PCA_Models*,

```
FUNCTIONNAME(A = Aut_Q_PCA_Models, B = "textstring", C = "textstring.png" )
```

should work, if you change line `dev.copy(png,"C", height = 400, width = 1000)` to `dev.copy(png, C, height = 400, width = 1000)` and `grid.text("B")` to `grid.text(B)`.

Comment: Thank you! that makes it at least print the figures now. But now my figures have (B) printed on them and the file is saved as (C), so not quite working. I'm guessing I'm making reference to these terms incorrectly in `FUNCTIONNAME`?

Comment: Thank you Qaswed! This is exactly what I was just doing myself once you had mentioned the first fix. It now works perfectly and I can save my 20+ images with ease. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: And don't call your function "FUNCTIONNAME". You wouldn't call your dog "Dogname" would you? Although that would be funny. "Here, Dogname..."

Comment: @Spacedman
These are simply working names which are in all caps so they stand out in the code.

Comment: Of course. But working names have a habit of finding their ways into systems. Try and use meaningful names and mark out your code with stand-out comments instead.